# Class in list comprehension has no attribute

Tags: python-3.x, list, class, attributes, list-comprehension

When I print the class in the list comprehension, it says it has no attribute "name", yet it clearly does. Also if I set the name for one it sets the name for all, as though they are all the same class?

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        if name:
            self.name = name
        else:
            self.name = "no name"

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name
                        
all_a = [A for i in range(5)]
other_a = []
    
for i in range(5):
    name = " name " + str(i)
    a = A(name)
    other_a.append(a)

print(all_a)

for a in all_a:
    print(a)
    print(a.name)

all_a[0].name = "all a zero"
all_a[1].name = "all a one"

for a in all_a:
    print(a)
    print(a.name)
        
for a in other_a:
    print(a)
```

If I remove the name parameter it still crashes out:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "no name"

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name
                        
all_a = [A for i in range(5)]
other_a = []
    
for i in range(5):
    name = " name " + str(i)
    a = A()
    other_a.append(a)

print(all_a)

for a in all_a:
    print(a)
    print(a.name)

all_a[0].name = "all a zero"
all_a[1].name = "all a one"

for a in all_a:
    print(a)
    print(a.name)
        
for a in other_a:
    print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that this line does not *initialize* objects:

```py
all_a = [A for i in range(5)]
```

It needs to be changed to something like:

```py
all_a = [A(str(i)) for i in range(5)]
```

Another option would be to declare `name` as a class attribute:

```py
class A(object):

    name = "Undefined"

    def __init__(self, name):
        if name:
            self.name = name
        else:
            self.name = "no name"

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name

all_a = [A for i in range(5)]

for a in all_a:
    print(a)
    print(a.name)
```

Output:

```
<class '__main__.A'>
Undefined
<class '__main__.A'>
Undefined
<class '__main__.A'>
Undefined
<class '__main__.A'>
Undefined
<class '__main__.A'>
Undefined
```

Comment: But if I get rid of the name parameter it still happens - I edited the post to show this.

Comment: It's still the same problem, `name` doesn't exist until the object is initialized. Maybe you meant to iterate over `other_a` in line 18 of the second code block?

Comment: yep, you need a class attribute name=" no name" and conditional in __init__ method maybe doesn't necessary, just self.name = name